# Draw a Line between a point and a second point from the same layer identified via value in the attribute table while digitalising (on the fly)

Tags: qgis, expression, qfield

I want to draw a line between a point I am digitalising and another point which I digitalised earlier. The second point should be identified via a specific ID (own column, here KartID).

For context: We map birds in QField. Sometimes you set a point for a bird, later you hear a, maybe, second bird but you are not sure whether it is the same bird as the first or not. So we want a line between theese to birds to indicate that these two might be the same.

The second bird is not necessarily digitalised directly in the next line of the attribute table. We want to have the possibility to have a field in the Formularlayout where we can put in an specific ID (containing of the code of the mapper an a unique ID, here KartID) for the second bird. This ID is in the line of the attribute table of the first point. After that a line should be drawn between those two...
Is that even possible?

[image]

E.g. I am dirgitalising point FK6, but I am not shure whether I hear the same bird as in FK1... so the line should appear between these two
remember: this is happening in the out field with QField so anything with the field calculator or Plug-In won't work I think...

[image]

Here is the attribute table of my test-geopackage. You can ignore the FID as it changes when you edit something (which happens in the field)...

Comment: You're aware that layers may only contain one type of vector data? Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I am aware of that, but there are some tweaks on how you can draw lines between Points in one layer via the masked symbollayer options in your layerproperties...
I want to achive that a Line (however) is drawn between two points: the one i am digitalising and a second one (that is not necessarily the input bevor (the way the masked symbollayer works)) 
Do you have any other Idea then the one by Oisin below?

Answer (score 1):

Great question. Here is a solution.

layername = observation

1. You need an additional attribute for your layer, which I have called observation. This is to hold the KartID of the observation point you want to link to. Let's call this KartID2.
2. Create a relation mylayer.kartID to mylayer.kartID2 as image below.

[image]

3. Add relation editor to your form so you can link to other observations as image below.

[image]

4. Create a virtual layer to create lines between the geometry of KartID1 and KartID2.

   select make_line(g1, g2)
   from (select o1.geometry as g1, o2.geometry as g2 from observation as o1 join observation as o2 on o1.KartID = o2.KartID2)

[image]

I have created a short mp4 video of it working [here](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AswVtlUsV-b_paYN6zXebOqlvnXAgA?e=7KB9rA)

Comment: Hey Oisin,again Thaks for your efforts!

Comment: Damn hitting enter posts.. It works!!! wonderfull! but I am not really sure wheater it works in Qfield. I will test that to morrow when I am back in the office. But for now it works :D

Comment: Hey Oisin and everybody else,
so we are testing the soloution in QField. We get up to the Point that we "made some Lines" in QGIS and exportet the project to QField, here the lines are shown (we wanted to test wheater virtual layers work in Qfield... and they do), but we are unable to enter new ones. The field where you normaly make a selection from the list is shown but not editable (there is no List shown from where to choose)... Any Idea why?

Comment: I will test at my end and come back to you. Perhaps in the configuration of the relation rewference field you need to add the edit button?

Comment: I think you mean: in layerproperties - formulars and fieldeditorconfiguration the configurations for your kartID and KarID2 !? yes the edit button in relationreference is on. it works in Qgis thou... Damn I feel that we are soooo close. And please take your Time, my colleague and I won't meet till next week